# Error: Mustra un registro de mas

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente detalle.

Estoy haciendo un programa de librería, que estoy haciendo con estructuras, punteros y funciones.

Mi problema es que cuando quiero imprimir los registros, en este caso ingreso 2 registros, se muestran 3: 2 son lo que ingresé y otro es un basura.

Muestro mi código:

```
//bibliotecas
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Declaramos la estructura Libros
typedef struct Libros {
    char Titulo[50];
    char Autor[50];
    int Codigo;
    float Precio;
    int num;
    struct Libros *Sig; //Puntero Siguiente para recorrer la lista enlazada
} Libro; //Libro es el tipo de dato para declarar la estructura

typedef Libro *LP; //Puntero al tipo de datdo Libro para no utilizar punteros de punteros

//declaramos las funciones
void InsertarLibros(LP *libro,int num);
void ImprimirLibros(LP *libro);
void EliminarLibros(LP *libro);

int main() {
    int num;
    LP libro; //Indica la cabeza de la lista enlazada, si la perdemos no podremos acceder a la lista
    char op;
    do {
        libro = NULL;  //Se inicializa el libro como NULL   ya que no hay ningun libro en la lista
        libro = (LP) malloc(1000 *sizeof(LP));
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t***LIBRERIA***\n");
        printf("\n\t\t 1 -> Ingresar Nuevo Libro.");
        printf("\n\t\t 2 -> Mostrar Libros y Salir");
        printf("\n\t\t Opcion: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);

        while (num != 2) {
            printf("\n\n\t\tTitulo: ");
            scanf("%s",libro->Titulo);
            printf("\n\t\tAutor: ");
            scanf("%s",libro->Autor);
            printf("\n\t\tCodigo: ");
            scanf("%d",&libro->Codigo);
            printf("\n\t\tPrecio: ");
            scanf("%f",&libro->Precio);
            InsertarLibros(&libro,num);
            printf("\n\n\t\t 1 -> Ingresar Nuevo Libro.");
            printf("\n\t\t 2 -> Mostrar Libros y Salir");
            printf("\n\t\t Opcion: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
        }

        ImprimirLibros(libro);
        printf("\n\n\t\tSe borra los libros cargados");
        EliminarLibros(&libro);
        printf("\n\n Quieres repetir el programa? \t S/N \n Opcion:");
        scanf("%s",&op);
    } while (op == 's'|| op == 'S');
    return 0;
}

void InsertarLibros(LP *libro, int num) {
    LP nuevo; //Creamos un nuevo nodo
    nuevo = (Libro*) malloc(1000 *sizeof(Libro)); //seteamos la memoria malloc con tipo de structura Libro
    //Asignamoslos valores a un nuevo libro
    nuevo->Titulo[50] = (**libro).Titulo[50];
    nuevo->Autor[50] = (**libro).Autor[50];
    nuevo->Codigo = (**libro).Codigo;
    nuevo->Precio = (**libro).Precio;
    nuevo->num = num;
    nuevo->Sig = *libro;
    *libro = nuevo; //libro pasa a ser el primero en la lista
}

void ImprimirLibros(LP *libro){
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t***LIBROS INGRESADOS***\n");
    while (*libro != NULL) { //Mientras libro sea diferente de NULL
        printf("\n\t\tTitulo: %s",(**libro).Titulo);
        printf("\n\t\tAutor: %s",(**libro).Autor);
        printf("\n\t\tCodigo: %d",(**libro).Codigo);
        printf("\n\t\tPrecio: $ %.2f",(**libro).Precio);
    }
}

void EliminarLibros(LP *libro) {
    LP actual; //Puntero auxiliar para elimanar correctamnte la lista

    while (*libro != NULL) { //Mientras libro  no sea NULL
        actual = *libro; //Actual toma el valor de libro
        *libro = (*libro)->Sig; //Libro avanza 1 posicionen la lista
        free(actual); //se libera la memoria de la posicion actual(el primer libro), y libro queda apuntando al que ahora es el primero
    }
}
```

Ya intenté varias maneras pero aún no logro hacerlo funcionar correctamente.

Muestro unas imágenes del error que les menciono:

[image: Ingreso correcto]

[image: Error]

El programa ingresa datos correctamente y los elimina.

Pero al mostrarlos, pone uno demás como se ve en las imágenes.

Espero me puedan ayudar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El origen de la basura está claro:

```
  void InsertarLibros(LP *libro, int num){
  LP nuevo; //Creamos un nuevo nodo
  nuevo = (Libro*) malloc(1000 *sizeof(Libro));//seteamos la memoria malloc con tipo de structura Libro
  //Asignamoslos valores a un nuevo libro
  nuevo->Titulo[50] = (**libro).Titulo[50]; ****************
  nuevo->Autor[50] = (**libro).Autor[50]; ****************
  nuevo->Codigo = (**libro).Codigo;
  nuevo->Precio = (**libro).Precio;
  nuevo->num = num;
  nuevo->Sig = *libro;
  *libro = nuevo; //libro pasa a ser el primero en la lista
  }
```

Las líneas marcadas no hacen lo que tú crees. La instrucción lo único que hace es copiar el carácter en la posición 50 de `(**libro).Titulo` en la posición 50 de `nuevo->Titulo`. Lo cual tiene dos cosas:

- Como Titulo es un array de 50 caracteres, los índices válidos van de 0 a 49. **50 está fuera del array y acceder a él es *undefined behavior.***
- El resto del contenido del array, que contiene "basura" (no ha sido inicializado), queda tal cual. Eso es lo que ves.

Para copiar un string, usa `strcpy`, por ejemplo

```
strcpy(nuevo->Titulo, (**libro).Titulo);
```

Luego queda la cuestión de que tengas tres en vez de dos, pero eso es sencillamente problema con tu lógica. Creas un primer libro en el bucle principal, y luego para cada libro que introduces invocas a *InsertarLibros* que añade un libro más. El programa hace lo que le dices que haga.

Ademas, haces

```
nuevo = (Libro*) malloc(1000 *sizeof(Libro));
```

Si vas a usar un `Libro` ¿por qué reservas espacio para 1000 de ellos?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @SJuan76, si funciona, pero aun me sigue mostrando 1 de mas, el seteo de malloc lo cambie asi ```nuevo = (libro*)malloc(1 *sizeof(libro));``` asi si funciona. Pero no me respeta el ```do while```