# Imprime solo el ultimo registro , dudas sobre la memoria dinamica y la funcion EliminarLibros

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente programa de una libreria en c. Estoy intentando que imprima todos los registros ingresados, pero a la hora de imprimir solo me imprime el ultimo registro que se realizo.
Todo esto lo estoy haciendo con punteros y memoria dinamica.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
 //librerias
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>


 //Declaramos la estructura Libros
 typedef struct Libros{
   char Titulo[50];
   char Autor[50];
   int Codigo;
   float Precio;
   int num;
   struct Libros *Sig;//Puntero Siguiente para recorrer la lista enlazada
   }Libro;//Libro es el tipo de dato para declarar la estructura

   typedef  Libro *LP; //Puntero al tipo de datdo Libro para no utilizar punteros de punteros

   //declaramos las funciones
   void InsertarLibros(LP *libro,int num);
   void ImprimirLibros(LP libro);
   void EliminarLibros(LP *libro);

   int main(){
      int num,cant=0,i;
      LP libro; //Indica la cabeza de la lista enlazada, si la perdemos no podremos acceder a la lista
      char op;
      do{
    
         system("cls");
         printf("\n\n\t\t\t***LIBRERIA***\n");
         printf("\n\t\t 1 -> Ingresar Nuevo Libro.");
         printf("\n\t\t 2 -> Mostrar Libros y Salir");
         printf("\n\t\t Opcion: ");
         scanf("%d",&num);
            
         while(num!=2 )//mientras que num sea diferente de 2
         {
            libro = (LP) malloc(1 *sizeof(LP));
            printf("\n\n\t\tTitulo: ");
            scanf("%s",libro->Titulo);
            printf("\n\t\tAutor: ");
            scanf("%s",libro->Autor);
            printf("\n\t\tCodigo: ");
            scanf("%d",&libro->Codigo);
            printf("\n\t\tPrecio: ");
            scanf("%f",&libro->Precio);
            InsertarLibros(&libro,num);
            printf("\n\n\t\t 1 -> Ingresar Nuevo Libro.");
            printf("\n\t\t 2 -> Mostrar Libros y Salir");
            printf("\n\t\t Opcion: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);   
        }

        ImprimirLibros(libro);
            
        printf("\n\n Quieres repetir el programa? \t S/N \n Opcion:");
        scanf("%s",&op);
    
        if(op == 's' || op == 'S')
        {
          EliminarLibros(&libro);
        }
    
  }while(op == 's'|| op=='S'); //se va a repetir el programa asta que el usuario ponga N

EliminarLibros(&libro);//Limpiamos la lista de libros

return 0;
}


void InsertarLibros(LP *libro, int num){
LP nuevo; //Creamos un nuevo nodo
nuevo = (Libro*) malloc(1 *sizeof(Libro));//seteamos la memoria malloc con tipo de structura Libro
//Asignamoslos valores a un nuevo libro
strcpy(nuevo->Titulo,(**libro).Titulo);
strcpy(nuevo->Autor,(**libro).Autor);
nuevo->Codigo = (**libro).Codigo;
nuevo->Precio = (**libro).Precio;
nuevo->num = num;
nuevo-> Sig = *libro;
*libro = nuevo; //libro pasa a ser el primero en la lista

}

void ImprimirLibros(LP libro){
//libro = (LP) malloc(1000 *sizeof(LP));
printf("\n\n\t\t\t***LIBROS INGRESADOS***\n");
while(libro != NULL){//Mientras libro sea diferente de NULL
    printf("\n\t\tTitulo: %s",libro->Titulo);
    printf("\n\t\tAutor: %s",libro->Autor);
    printf("\n\t\tCodigo: %d",libro->Codigo);
    printf("\n\t\tPrecio: $ %.2f",libro->Precio);
    printf("\n\n");
    libro = libro->Sig;
}
}

void EliminarLibros(LP *libro){
LP actual; //Puntero auxiliar para elimanar correctamnte la lista

while(*libro != NULL){//Mientras libro  no sea NULL
    strcpy(actual->Autor,(**libro).Autor);//Actual toma el valor de libro
    strcpy(actual->Titulo,(**libro).Titulo);
    actual->Codigo = (**libro).Codigo;
    actual->Precio = (**libro).Precio;
    *libro = (*libro)->Sig;//Libro avanza 1 posicionen la lista
    free(actual);//se libera la memoria de la posicion actual(el primer libro), y libro queda apuntando al que ahora es el primero
}
}
```

Como les menciono solo imprime el ultimo registro ingresado y tambien me gustaria saber si la funcion de **EliminarLibros** esta bien.

En lo de la memoria dinamica tengo mis dudas si esta bien `libro = (LP) malloc(1 *sizeof(LP));` esta es en el **main** y la siguiente `nuevo = (Libro*) malloc(1 *sizeof(Libro));` esta en la funcion **InsertarLibros**.

Envio capturas de como funciona el programa:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395714/error-mustra-un-registro-de-mas?

Comment: @CandidMoe si, pero es otro problema el que tengo

Comment: @CandidMoe ya elimine la otra pregunta. para que no existan duplicados.